# No current header for value line when importing impex in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

```
itemtype code="CartPageConfig"  jaloclass="de.hybris.platform.jalo.config.CartPageConfig">
             <deployment table="CartPageConfig" typecode="21033" />
             <attributes>
                 <attribute qualifier="code" type="java.lang.String">
                     <modifiers unique="true" optional="false"/>
                     <persistence type="property" />
                 </attribute>
                 <attribute qualifier="shipToStores" type="AllowedStoresList">
                     <description> List of stores where the notification should be shown </description>
                     <persistence type="property"/>
                 </attribute>
             </attributes>
             <indexes>
                 <index name="code" unique="true">
                     <key attribute="code"/>
                 </index>
             </indexes>
         </itemtype>
```

And the following item to insert data for the above item:

```
CartPageConfig;code[unique=true];shipToStores;baseStores(uid)
;cartPageConfig;US;en-US-PT02
```

I get the following error when trying to import the above impex:

```
CartPageConfig,,,,;code[unique=true];shipToStores;# no current header for value line

 ,,,,;cartPageConfig;US;# no current header for value line


 23.07.2019 16:12:06: ERROR: de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.ImpExException: Can not resolve any more lines ... Aborting further passes (at pass 2). Finally could not import 2 lines![HY-123]
```

Comment: Missing the header in the impex, like INSERT, UDATE, REMOVE, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
INSERT_UPDATE CartPageConfig;code[unique=true];shipToStores;baseStores(uid)
;cartPageConfig;US;en-US-PT02
```